"Your move, bud."
Loosely inspired by What do you see?

Given the image below, which letter, A - D, is correct? Why?


A. The guy now has eyes. For C, we'd have to interpret him as wearing a hat, and the point on the new "flap" looks weird.  Also, he has no eyes! Other two better be burnt with fire.

Must we even default to the male gender for pictures of graphs?

@GregMartin yes, women around the world are probably very angry that they have not been identified with these abstract graphs. Luckily you are here to fight for this very important cause.

The answer is:

B

As it's the

Only valid move in Sprouts; the other options involve using a dead cell.
If you don't know what Sprouts is, this Vsauce2 video should help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKsTGdN-4_M\
The title of 'Your move, bud' is a double pun: both because it is your, i.e. the solver's move in this game of sprouts, and because a bud is a synonym for a sprout.


I believe the answer is

 B

Reasoning

 The Title "Your Move, Bud." refers to the game sprouts since it is a turn based game and bud can also mean seed bud or sprout.
 Sprouts is a turn based game in which the goal is to get the other player not to connect any more dots. Each dot can only have three lines to it so four lines are impossible.
 Since there can only be three lines A, C, & D are impossible while B is.


As others have said:

 B

Because:

 It's the only one that doesn't create a 4-way junction. No knowledge of any game required.

